# How to include Micro symbol (µ) in Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, testcomplete

I need to use the following regex in my Javascript code:

```
/\D*(\d+)\s*([TGMkmµnp]).*/g
```

However, the `µ` symbol is causing syntax error.
How can I fix this?

The error message is:

> At "value = str.replace(/(+)(TGMk"
>       error110: SYNTAX ERROR while lexing character "µ".

I am using TestComplete software.

My code is as simple as this:

```
function GetVoltageDbl(str)
{
  var value = str.replace(/\D*(\d+)\s*([TGMkµmnp]).*/g, "$1");
  var prefix = str.replace(/\D*(\d+)\s*([TGMkµmnp]).*/g, "$2");

  Log.Message(value);
  Log.Message(prefix);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `u` modifier?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please provide the exact error. Likely an encoding problem which can be fixed by saving the file in UTF-8.

Comment: What syntax error?

Comment: no "syntax error". Another cause?

Comment: Added more information regarding the error. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `\u03BC` instead? e.g. `str.replace(/\D*(\d+)\s*([TGMk\u0370mnp])` or something

Comment: Just tested in Chrome *without* specifying a `charset` and it worked without problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing µ with \u03BC as follows:

```
/\D*(\d+)\s*([TGMkm\u03BCnp]).*/g
```

Answer (score -6):

Please try this \µ . It's need to help

Comment: Tried. Not working. Still give me the same error.